# Laravel - How to validate fields in maatwebsite excel import

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel-5.8 and Maatwebsite/excel-3.1 package in Excel to import users profile in a web application.

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use App\StudentInfo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class FirstStudentSheetImport implements OnEachRow, WithHeadingRow
{
  protected $class, $section;

  public function onRow(Row $row)
  {   
     $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();

     if($rowIndex >= 200)
        return; // Not more than 200 rows at a time

     $row = $row->toArray();

     $this->class = (string) $row[__('class')];
     $this->section = (string) $row[__('section')];

    $user = [
        'name'           => $row[__('name')],
        'email'          => $row[__('email')],
        'password'       => Hash::make($row[__('password')]),
        'active'         => 1,
        'code'           => auth()->user()->code,
        'address'        => $row[__('address')],
        'about'          => $row[__('about')],
        'pic_path'       => '',
         'birthday'             => $row[__('birthday')]?? date('Y-m-d'),
        'phone_number'   => $row[__('phone_number')],
        'verified'       => 1,
        'section_id'     => $this->getSectionId(),
        'blood_group'    => $row[__('blood_group')],
        'nationality'    => $row[__('nationality')],
        'gender'         => $row[__('gender')],
     ];

     $tb = create(User::class, $user);
}
```

From the code above, how do I validate:

1. birthday to be less than current date
2. phone_number to be integer and 13 digits
3. email to be strictly email
4. How do I display list of fields with errors in it fails
5. How do I display imported files if successful
6. How do I remove the first row (header)

Comment: Perhaps re-think your approach. For something like an import, where you have X rows of data, you can have the user import the data, you validate all rows before trying to insert, and report back to the user if there are any issues. They fix them, re-import, and repeat that process until there are no issues. Then do the insert. It's a multi-step process, but prevents issues with partial inserts, lengthy validation/insert time,UI/UX concerns, etc.

Comment: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html